# Binomial Coefficients sum

Tags: binomial-coefficients, gm.general-mathematics, closed-form-expressions

Any idea on whether or not $$\sum_{i = 0}^b(-1)^i\binom{b}{i}\binom{a+b-i-1}{a-i}$$
has a closed formula on $a$ and $b$ (and on what it is, in case it does)?

It is supposed that $b \le a$.

Comment: [Searching with Approach Zero](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum_%7Bi%20%3D%200%7D%5Eb(-1)%5Ei%5Cbinom%7Bb%7D%7Bi%7D%5Cbinom%7Ba%2Bb-i-1%7D%7Ba-i%7D%24&p=1) leads [this AoPS thread](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h16482p114715). It also links to Exercise 4 in [this problem set](http://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/t/17f/hw4os.pdf) from Darij Grinberg.

Comment: Cross posted here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3909793/interesting-binomial-coefficients-sum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a combinatorial proof that the expression is $0$.  Both sides of the identity count the number of $(b-1)$-subsets of $\{1,\dots,a+b-1\}$ that include $\{1,\dots,b\}$.  Because $b > b-1$, this count is obviously $0$, establishing the RHS.  For the LHS, apply inclusion-exclusion, where the $b$ properties to be avoided are that $j$ does not appear for $j \in \{1,\dots,b\}$.  More generally, this argument shows that
$$\sum_{i=0}^b (-1)^i \binom{b}{i} \binom{a+b-1-i}{k} = 0$$
for $k < b$, and it does not require $b \le a$.

Comment: Awesome, @RobPratt! I'm choosing your answer for its beauty and its clarity.

Answer (score 3):

This is always zero. Combinatorially, consider $a + b - 1$ balls. Choose $a$ balls, and color them into black and white such that only balls $1, \ldots, b$ can be black. The sum in OP is the difference between the colorings with even and odd numbers of black balls ($i$ being the number of black balls). However, valid colorings of any set $S$ of size $a$ cancel out. Indeed, $B = S \cap \{1, \ldots, b\}$ is not empty, thus the sum is $\sum_{A \subseteq B} (-1)^{|A|} = 0$.

Comment: Awesome, @Mikhail! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

$(1+x)^b=\sum_{k=0}^{b} \binom{b}{k}x^k$

Now, $\binom{a+b-1-i}{a-i}=\binom{a+b-1-i}{b-1}$...$(1)$

And, $(1+x)^{-b}=1-\binom{b}{b-1}x+\binom{b+1}{b-1}x^2-..\color{cadetblue}{(-1)^{a-b}\binom{a-1}{b-1}x^{a-b}+(-1)^{a-b+1}\binom{a}{b-1}x^{a-b+1}......+(-1)^{a}\binom{a+b-1}{b-1}x^{a+1}}+.... \tag{2}$

Multiplying (1) and (2) we easily see that the coefficient of $x^a$ in r.h.s $$(-1)^a\sum_{I=0}^{b}(-1)^i\binom{b}{i}\binom{a+b-i-1}{a-i}$$.

But the left hand side of $(1)×(2)$ is 1. Hence, the coefficient of $x^a, a\geq 1$ is $0$.

Hence, $$\sum_{I=0}^{b}(-1)^i\binom{b}{i}\binom{a+b-i-1}{a-i}=0$$

Comment: Awesome, @Alapan! Thank you! I just think you've misspelled the first equation.

Comment: Oh. Yes. I misspelled equation 1. Thank you.