# An ambitiouser binomial coefficients sum

Tags: binomial-coefficients, gm.general-mathematics, closed-form-expressions

I [asked](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/376606/binomial-coefficients-sum?noredirect=1#comment955008_376606) how to calculate $$\sum_{i = 0}^b(-1)^i\binom{b}{i}\binom{a+b-i-1}{a-i}$$ and got amazing answers. A bit later, however, I figured I needed something rather more complicated: I need to find the value of $$\sum_{i = 0}^k(-1)^i\binom{b}{i}\binom{a+b-i-1}{a-i},$$ where $k$ can be any integer between $0$ and $b$. Is there any closed formula for that?

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5B%28-1%29%5Ei+Binomial%5Bb%2Ci%5DBinomial%5Ba%2Bb-i-1%2Ca-i%5D%2C+%7Bi%2C0%2Ck%7D%5D

Comment: `Sum[(-1)^i*Binomial[b, i]*Binomial[a + b - i - 1, a - i], {i, 0, k}]` results in $$\frac{(-1)^{k+1} (k+1) (-a-b+k+1) \binom{b}{k+1} \binom{a+b-k-2}{a-k-1}}{a b} $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WolframAlpha claims it is
$$\frac{(-1)^{k + 1} (k + 1) (-a - b + k + 1) \binom{b}{k + 1} \binom{a + b - k - 2}{a - k - 1}}{a b},$$
and you can absorb the $k+1$ and $b$, yielding
$$\frac{(-1)^{k+1} (-a - b + k + 1) \binom{b-1}{k} \binom{a + b - k - 2}{a - k - 1}}{a}.$$
A little simpler:
$$\frac{(-1)^k b \binom{b-1}{k} \binom{a + b - k - 1}{b}}{a}.$$

Comment: Nice! I wasn't aware of the fact that WolframAlpha did such kind of calculation. Once we have the formula, it can be shown by induction. Thank you, @RobPratt!